# Error on 'nlohmann::json::from_bson()': syntax error while parsing BSON cstring

Tags: c++, json, bson

I have a binary `std::string` (length = 560):

> 01111011001000100111010101110011011001010111001001101110011000010110110101100101001000100011101000100000001000100100110001101001011011100110111101111001001000100010110000100000001000100111000001100001011100110111001101110111011011110111001001100100001000100011101000100000001000100011000100110010001100110011010000110101001101100010001000101100001000000010001001100101011011010110000101101001011011000010001000111010001000000010001001101100011010010110111001101111011110010100000001101101011000010110100101101100001011100110001101101111011011010010001001111101

When I convert it to ASCII (using online websites), I get the JSON string I want:

> {"username": "Linoy", "password": "123456", "email": "linoy@mail.com"}

I want to convert the binary `std::string` to a `nlohmann::json` object, so I use `nlohmann::json::from_bson()`.
To do it, I need to send to `from_bson()` function a `std::vector<uint8_t>`
So I convert the `std::string` to the needed `std::vector<uint8_t>`:

```
using JSON = nlohmann::json;
std::vector<uint8_t> vec;   
vec.assign(to_convert.begin(), to_convert.end());
JSON json_object = JSON::from_bson(vec);
```

The problem is I get an error on the when calling `from_bson()`, is that I get an error:

> [json.exception.parse_error.110] parse error at byte 561: syntax error while parsing BSON cstring: unexpected end of input

**That's it. That's my problem. Can someone help me?**

---

**If you wanna see where is the exact error, follow this:**

I tried to place some breakpoints, and found out that the code is throwing an exception in `json.hpp: line 24338`, `sax_parse()` function (line 10 in this codeblock):

```
template<typename InputType>
JSON_HEDLEY_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT
    static basic_json from_bson(InputType&& i,
        const bool strict = true,
        const bool allow_exceptions = true)
{
    basic_json result;
    detail::json_sax_dom_parser<basic_json> sdp(result, allow_exceptions);
    auto ia = detail::input_adapter(std::forward<InputType>(i));
    const bool res = binary_reader<decltype(ia)>(std::move(ia)).sax_parse(input_format_t::bson, &sdp, strict);
    return res ? result : basic_json(value_t::discarded);
}
```

When going deeper, inside `sax_parse()` function, it throw the exception in `json.hpp: line 7743`, `parse_bson_internal()` function (line 10 in this codeblock):

```
bool sax_parse(const input_format_t format,
                json_sax_t* sax_,
                const bool strict = true,
                const cbor_tag_handler_t tag_handler = cbor_tag_handler_t::error)
{
            sax = sax_;
            bool result = false;

            switch (format)
            {
            case input_format_t::bson:
                result = parse_bson_internal();
                break;
```

When going deeper, inside `parse_bson_internal()`, it throw the exception in `json.hpp: line 7803`, `pars_bson_element_list(false)` function (line 9 in this codeblock):

```
    bool parse_bson_internal()
    {
        std::int32_t document_size{};
        get_number<std::int32_t, true>(input_format_t::bson, document_size);

        if (JSON_HEDLEY_UNLIKELY(!sax->start_object(std::size_t(-1))))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (JSON_HEDLEY_UNLIKELY(!parse_bson_element_list(/*is_array*/false)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return sax->end_object();
    }
```

Comment: A string of '0' and '1' is not, what is usually considered *binary* data.

Comment: @JakobStark What do you mean, so what is my alternative? At the end, the `std::vector<uint8_t>` is converted and it has some 0&1 values.

Comment: You don't need a vector of 0 and 1 values but a vector, where the 8 bits of the first element correspond to the first 8 0&1 values in your string.

Comment: Also that does not make your data bson. Your *binary string* is still the binary representation of the json string. The first 8 bits for example correspond to the '{' ASCII character. The following three values are the same `0b01111011 = 0x7b = '{'`